# Office 365 installation stuck with one minute remaining on running package scripts

Tags: macos, install, office-365

I wiped and re-installed macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 on an older MacBook Air (11″, 2013).  Then I tried to download Office 365.  It got as far as "one minute remaining" on "Running Package Scripts", then it hung.  I tried force-quitting and re-starting.  It won't let me.  So I am stuck here. What can I do?

Comment: While your machine specs are useful, your question title should summarise the problem you're facing. I've edited the title in an attempt to represent the problem, but feel free to [edit] further. Also, Macs run macOS and iPhone/iPad runs iOS.

Answer (score 1):

The ‘running package scripts’ step does take a while and Installer is not able to accurately suggest how long this step will take. My guess is it wasn't ‘hung’ but you didn't wait long enough at that step — it can take numerous minutes and is working hard.

You can forcibly shut down the machine by holding the power button until the machine turns off. This wouldn't usually be necessary, but it probably is now, depending on the steps you took to attempt to interrupt the installation.

I recommend attempting to install Office once again (as a partial installation isn't ideal) and letting the installer work through the steps it requires without attempting to interrupt it.

Comment: the "running package scripts" went on for more than a couple of hours, so I think it hung... and I did shut off the computer as suggested, tried re-installed 3X.. finally, I selected only word/excel/powerpoint to install (rather than the entire Office suite, then it worked...

Answer (score 0):

If you go to applications in finder, click on the utilities folder and select activity monitor, you can make it finish by double clicking on installd, making it quit, and then it should immediately finish installing office!